# Group By or Case Logic Issue (Similar to SUMIFS in Excel)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a temp table and I'm trying to sum data but can't seem to get the logic right for it. The table contains customer level data and now I'm trying to aggregate it by fiscal year, quarter, and product description. I'm trying to sum by going back 1 year and using the same quarter to sum the # of units sold.

I can do this in excel, but the table is too large for that. This is what the formula in Excel looks like:

```
=SUMIFS(Units,FiscalYearQuarter >= Concat(FiscalYear -1 & FiscalQuarter, FiscalYearQuarter <= Concat(FiscalYear, FiscalQuarter)
```

Here's an example of the table:

[image]

Here's what the results should looks like (This does not include productdescription, but I will want to add that in):

[image]

Every time I try to group by or do a Sum(Case When...) I keep getting the results only by the fiscal year/quarter instead of the sum of historical for 1 year.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` will work (although I don't quite understand your Excel logic with concatenation):

```
SELECT t1.FiscalYear, t1.FiscalQuater, sum(t2.UnitsPurchased)
  FROM `table` t1
       LEFT JOIN `table` t2
          ON    (    t1.FiscalYear = t2.FiscalYear + 1
                 AND t1.FiscalQuater < t2.FiscalQuater)
             OR (    t1.FiscalYear = t2.FiscalYear
                 AND t1.FiscalQuater >= t2.FiscalQuater)
GROUP BY t1.FiscalYear, t1.FiscalQuater
```

**EDIT 1**
modified query based on author's feedback

Comment: Thanks bc004346, the problem I'm running into is grouping by the FiscalYear, FiscalQuarter, but the sum needs to sum ranges. Example FY 2017 Qtr 1 should sum anything from 1 year ago to that time (FY 2016 Qtr 1 → FY 2017 Qtr 1). So the last row in the data is summing anything with FiscalYearQuarter >= 20161 which is 10 units. FY 2016 Qtr 4 should sum all units from FY 2015 Qtr 4 → FY 2016 Qtr 4 so summing everything for FiscalYearQuarter > 20154, but <= 20164

Comment: I could do this for each customer and just add multiple columns. But how to do the group by fiscalyear, fiscalquarter so that it didn't have to be done in a new column every time?  `Select Sum(Case When FiscalYearQuarter >= 20121 and FiscalYearQuarter <= 20131 Then BoxesPurchased Else 0 End) as Q1_2013Units, Sum(Case When FiscalYearQuarter >= 20122 and FiscalYearQuarter <= 20132 Then BoxesPurchased Else 0 End) as Q2_2013Units, Sum(Case When FiscalYearQuarter >= 20123 and FiscalYearQuarter <= 20133 Then BoxesPurchased Else 0 End) as Q3_2013Units From #Final Where CustID = '000'`